# How to process the results of a recursive descent like an array?

Tags: arrays, jq

I want to filter for all values of a certain key and then apply further computation on an array of them, e.g. sum them up.

```
{
    "v": 0,
    "child": {
        "v": 2,
        "child": {
            "v": 3,
            "child": {
                "v": null
            }
        },
    "list": [{"v":4}]
    }
}
```

Intuitively I try  `jq '..|.v? | add'` and expect `9` but get an error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:12): Cannot iterate over number (0)
exit status 5
```

So I guess it treats the first element as an array, instead of treating all filtered values as an array.

With `jq '..|.v?'` I can print them out:

```
0
2
3
null
null
4
```

But they don't seem to be an array (because ´echo "[0,2,3,null,null,4]" | jq 'add'´ works).

So what is the "type" of the result of `jq '..|.v?'` and how can I treat it as an array?

Comment: @oguzismail not obvious to me I guess, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`add` expects an array, so you could wrap your stream up (`[..|.v?]`), or much better, define a stream-based version of `add`:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+$x);

sigma(.. | .v?)
```

(Since `[]|add` yields `null`, you might like to replace `0` by `null` in the above def.)